# Match Against... SEMI-Literall

Tags: sql, search, match, against

I want to do a match-against query in where all the words of the string must be necessary to be in the field, but it needs to accept mistakes or words uncomplete.

My actual script is like this:

```
$search= '+'.str_replace(" ","% +",$_POST["searchtext"]);
```

With this i convert "this is my text" to "+this +is +my +text" so all the words are necessary in the search, and then i make

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name,surname MATCH (name,surname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS coincidences FROM users MATCH (name,surname) AGAINST (:search2 IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY coincidences");
$query->execute(array('search' => $search,'search2' => $search));
```

The problem is that if in my DB there is an "Stephen Hawking" and i search "Stephen Hawk" it wont appear... How can i fix this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Its done...

```
$search= '+'.str_replace(" ","* +",$_POST["searchtext"]).'*';
```

:D

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.